# @Autowired and configuring beans different way

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have

```
public class Foo
{
}
```

and I have

```
public class Bar
{

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

}
```

Now, I want to be able to configure Foo differently. So, `Bar` will have the Foo which will use one `Resource` and `Baz` will have the `Foo` with different `Resource`.

I tried to add it in .xml:

```
<bean id="Foo1" class="com.something.Foo" >
  <constructor-arg value="#{ appProperties.resourece1 }"/>
</bean>

<bean id="Foo2" class="com.something.Foo" >
  <constructor-arg value="#{ appProperties.resourece2 }"/>
</bean>
```

I created a constructor

```
public class Foo
{

    public Foo(Resource resource)
    {
    }
}
```

And I used

```
 @Autowired @Qualifier("Foo1")
 Foo foo;
```

However, it throws No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ssomething.Foo.()
So, it looks like it ignores .xml at all.

What is the right way of solving this, because it looks like I am doing something wrong? Should I dump `@Autowired` at all in such case?

Comment: Please provide a short but reproducible example. I'm unsure of your final configuration.

Comment: Basically, I'd like to see the XML configuration, how it is loaded, and the full stack trace.

Comment: Try marking the constructor itself as `@Autowired`

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: paste your `applicationContext.xml`